# AMP Validations error

Tags: validation, responsive, accelerated-mobile-page

I am doing AMP Validation that I want to clear all the errors. Most of the errors based on this type.

**Error Line:**

> The tag 'img' may only appear as a descendant of tag 'noscript'. Did
>   you mean 'amp-img'?

how to solve this?

Comment: AMP HTML files don't support the normal HTML img tag. change your img tag with amp-img .. readmore at https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/

Comment: yeah thats fine @RyanAW but i am not making the whole site to become in amp, already the site gone for live. I just using amp only for images and videos for mobile only.. then what about desktop i have used those <img> tags for desktop.

Comment: you may have two different pages for mobile & desktop users. For amp mobile users you need to make that page fully AMP valid page. That's the requirement.

Comment: then the file will be too know? @RyanAW